# Firebase: How to fetch objects from database from multiple IDs in to one list?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I have a table of user-posts exactly like described in the Firebase documentation here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

```
//From docs

var updates = {};

//I'm not actually doing this
updates['/posts/' + newPostKey] = postData; 

//I'm doing this
updates['/user-posts/' + uid + '/' + newPostKey] = postData; 

return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

I also have a user table which contains a list of "friend-ids":

```
"users": {
  "USER-ID-1": {
    ...
    "friends": [
      "FRIEND-ID-1",
      "FRIEND-ID-2"
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm wondering how I can fetch all objects from "user-posts" where the ID is in the friends-array of the current user?

This is not described in the documentation, and I guess its the right data-model if they have used it as an example...?
I have not found any example on how to fetch all instances from a table based on multiple IDs.

**So: How to get all user-posts from FRIEND-ID-1 and FRIEND-ID-2 returned as ONE list that I can loop over and show in the view.**

Is this possible? If not, how can this be achieved?

Thanks for all help! :)

Comment: Querying Firebase is a pain, especially if you don't flatten your database. For ex. if you have Posts with fields - **Type** (options for type are `A` and `B`) and **Length** (options for length are `long` and `short`) and you want to get all posts of type A and length long, you should create another data row, like you have now `Posts`. And it could be named **Posts_A_Long**. So every time you create post with type A and length long, you also add it to this table. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures

Comment: How can I flatten my example correctly to be able to fetch the correct data, then? Do I need to have one table for each combination of user-and-friend? Seems too much...

Comment: `FRIEND-ID-1` is its `uid`? If so, you can query their posts one by one and aggregate that on client side, as Firebase does'nt support aggregation on server side. Probably better is to convert Firebase's promises into Rxjs's Observables and merge them as wanted.

Comment: I was hoping you wouldn't say that... Okay, will try that then. The problem is then that I cannot directly listen to changes on that list.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should get you on the right track.

These are in my constructor:

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, public afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}
```

and here is my methods for getting my frieds posts:

```
  getFriendPosts(){
    this.getListOfFriends().then(data => {
      data.forEach(friend => {
        this.db.database.ref("user-posts/" + friend.uid).once('value').then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach(post => {
            console.log(post.val());
          });
        }).catch((err) => {
           console.log(err);
        });
      });
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  getListOfFriends(){
    let items: any = [];
    var mList = [];
    return this.db.database.ref("users/" + this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid + "/friends").once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach(user => {
        mList.push(user.val());
      });
      return items = mList;
    }).catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
  }
```

PS: I havn't tested this code. Also I recommend setting up you list of friends UID as objects and not string.

```
"users": {
  "USER-ID-1": {
    ...
    "friends": [
      "FRIEND-ID-1",
      "FRIEND-ID-2"
    ]
  }
}
```

to =>

```
"users": {
  "USER-ID-1": {
    ...
    "friends": [
      {uid: "FRIEND-ID-1"},
      {uid: "FRIEND-ID-2"}
    ]
  }
}
```

Or if you want it to be observable list I would try this:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

items: Observable<any[]>;

this.items = db.list("user-posts/" + friend.uid).valueChanges();
```

So maybe something like this:

```
  listOfAllPosts: any = [];
  friendPostsList: Observable<any[]>;

  getFriendPosts(){
    this.getListOfFriends().then(data => {
      data.forEach(friend => {
        this.friendPostsList = this.db.list("user-posts/" + friend.uid).valueChanges();
        this.listOfAllPosts.push(this.friendPostsList);
      });
    }).catch(err =>{
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this. The "FRIEND-ID-1" Was just and example. I use UID, not strings.